# Issue with db subnet group subnet ids

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have some terraform code to spin up a db subnet group like so:

```
resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "subnet" {
name = "db subnet"
subnet_ids =  ["${var.rds_subnet_id}"]
}
```

However, I get this error:

aws_db_subnet_group.subnet: DBSubnetGroupDoesNotCoverEnoughAZs: DB Subnet Group doesn't meet 
availability zone coverage requirement. Please add subnets to cover at least 2 availability zones. 
  Current
coverage: 1

However, if I hardcode the subnet ids in the variable, this error goes.

Any idea why?

Comment: What do you mean by "if I hardcode the subnet ids in the variable, this error goes"? Can you show an example? And how are you setting the `rds_subnet_id` variable and what does it get set to when it fails?

Comment: If the line: subnet_ids =  ["${var.rds_subnet_id}"]
Is changed with subnet ids, e.g. "subnet-1", "subnet-2", the code works fine. But I want to use variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error clearly states, you need to provide at least 2 subnets. Your current terraform code only provides one subnet, and as you mentioned when you hard-code 2 subnets it works. Your code needs to look something like this:

```
resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "subnet" {
    name = "db subnet"
    subnet_ids =  ["${var.rds_subnet_id1}", "${var.rds_subnet_id2}"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks I had a list variable I was tryin to pass, but this works too.

Comment: To pass a list variable, with Terraform 0.12 anyway, you would simply use `subnet_ids = var.subnet_ids`